# Struggling with waiting for transfer completion with VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga, spi

I'm needing to do continual SPI communication to read values from a dual channel ADC I have, and have written a kinda state-machine to do so. However, it doesn't seem to be getting into the state that reads the second channel and I can't figure out why. here's the VHDL...

```
SPI_read: process (mclk)
                                                        --command bits: Start.Single.Ch.MSBF....
    constant query_x: unsigned(ADC_datawidth-1 downto 0) := "11010000000000000";    -- Query ADC Ch0 ( inclinometer x-axis)
    constant query_y: unsigned(ADC_datawidth-1 downto 0) := "11110000000000000";    -- Query ADC Ch1 ( inclinometer y-axis)

begin

    if rising_edge(mclk) then

        -- when SPI is not busy, change state and latch Rx data from last communication
        if (SPI_busy = '0') then

            case SPI_action is
                when SETUP => 
                    SPI_pol <= '0'; -- Clk low when not active
                    SPI_pha <= 1;       -- First edge is half an SCLK period after CS activated
                    SPI_action <= READ_X;
                when READ_X =>
                    SPI_Tx_buf <= query_x; -- Load in command
                    y_data <= "00000" & SPI_Rx_buf(11 downto 1);
                    SPI_send <= '1';
                    SPI_action <= READ_Y;
                when READ_Y =>
                    SPI_Tx_buf <= query_y; -- Load in command
                    x_data <= "00000" & SPI_Rx_buf(11 downto 1);
                    SPI_send <= '1';
                    SPI_action <= READ_X;
            end case;

        else
            SPI_send <= '0'; -- Deassert send pin
        end if;

    end if;

end process SPI_read;
```

The command is sent to the Tx buffer, and the value from the last received data is written to a signal which is output to some seven segment displays. A pulse from SPI_send is required to start the transfer, and when started, SPI_busy is set high until the transfer is completed.

Right now it'll only send the query_x over SPI, and I can know this since I can see it on the scope. Interestingly, however, It's outputting the same value to both displays which leads me to think that it's still getting into it's READ_Y state, but not changing the Tx Data it's outputting.

I've been staring at this code for hours now, and I can't figure it out. Sometimes a fresh pair of eyes makes life easier, so if you spot anything please let me know.
Also, I'm very open to suggestions of better ways to deal with this, I'm just learning VHDL so I'm not even sure I'm doing things the right way mostly!

Comment: I do not see the code for the tx portion and the state declarations.  One suggestion would be to stick to the basic one process state machine template.  Simplest to make busyX and busyY states.

Comment: also when you are learning HDL simulation is your friend, it makes debugging issues like this very easy.

Comment: Sorry, should have said the SPI master is a component, which returns SPI_busy when it's transmitting/receiving. This is just one process from my top level design so didn't want to include too much that might have been irrelevant. SPI_action starts in 'SETUP' state and then doesn't return there once running. Not sure I understand what you mean by your last sentence though.

Comment: You really should simulate this design, that will tell you what the state of each signal is for a cycle of transactions.  I don't see anything obviously wrong with the code itself but it could be a problem or an incorrect assumption about how the spi_writer module works or just a bug.  ie How many clock cycles does it take from SPI_send going high to busy going high?  Also is everything running in the same clock domain?

Comment: I wrote the SPI component myself and fully simulated it. But you're right, I should probably simulate it now as it is. But yes, everything is running off the master clock. I'm just generally unsure though if this is even the right approach for a 'wait to complete' type behaviour. All I want to do is send a pulse on SPI_send, that needs to be shorter than the transmission period, and  wait for SPI_busy to be de-asserted. I struggled to find anything written about this sort of behaviour anywhere though.

Comment: There are a few things that are not very good with your code, first of all, you must have a "when  others =>" in the list of your states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are thinking along the right basic lines, but there are various things not-quite-right with your state machine - as the other answers say - and these are easy to discover in simulation.

For example

```
        when READ_X =>
            SPI_Tx_buf <= query_x; -- Load in command
            y_data <= "00000" & SPI_Rx_buf(11 downto 1);
            SPI_send <= '1';
            SPI_action <= READ_Y;
```

Now if SPI_Busy stays low for a second cycle, this will clearly not stay in state READ_X but transition directly to READ_Y which is probably not what you want.

A more normal state machine would treat the states as outermost, and interpret the input signals differently for each state :

```
   case SPI_Action is             
      when READ_X => 
                     if SPI_Busy = '0' then    -- Wait here if busy
                        SPI_Tx_buf <= query_x; -- Load in command
                        y_data <= "00000" & SPI_Rx_buf(11 downto 1);
                        SPI_send <= '1';
                        SPI_action <= READING_X;
                     end if;
      when READING_X =>
                     if SPI_Busy = '1' then   -- command accepted
                        SPI_action <= READ_Y; -- ready to send next one
                     end if;
      when READ_Y => 
                     if SPI_Busy = '0' then    -- Wait here if busy
```

You can see that this version treats the Busy signal as a handshake, and only progresses when Busy changes state. I am certain you can make your approach (IF outermost) work if you want, but you will have tofigure out how to apply the handshaking principle yourself.

There is also no "Idle" state where neither X or Y is being read; this SM will read X and Y alternately as fast as it can. Commonly you would read them both, then return to Idle until some other Start signal commanded you to leave Idle and perform a fresh set of reads.

You can possibly also make the state machine more robust with a "when others" clause. It's not a must, if you guarantee to cover all your defined states, but it can make maintenance easier. On the other hand, without such a clause, the compilers will let you know of any uncovered states, guarding against mistakes.

There is a myth that a "when others" clause is essential and synthesis tools generate safer but less optimal state machines from a "when others" clause. However there are synthesis attributes or command line options to control how synth tools generate state machines.

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks once again Brian! That's exactly what I couldn't work out what to do, never occurred to me to have separate states just to wait to change state again.

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing my comments so far into an answer.

Simulate this process/module with your SPI master component.

Your approach is generally correct but I would suggest you re-architect your state machine slightly to put explicit wait states in between each spi transaction (wait_x, wait_y) and maybe have a more robust handshake between the modules, ie stay in read_x until busy goes high, then stay in wait_x until busy goes low.

It looks like send is getting asserted for two cycles and you are transition through both read_x and read_y each cycle.
[image: timing diagram]

Drawn from this program
http://wavedrom.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/editor.html
with this source:

```
{ "signal" : [
  { "name": "clk",           "wave": "P........" },
  { "name": "busy",          "wave": "0..1.|0..1"},
  { "name": "SPI_Action",    "wave": "====.|.==.",   "data": ["SETUP", "READ_X", "READ_Y", "READ_X", "READ_Y", "READ_X", "READ_Y", ] },
  { "name": "SPI_send",      "wave": "0.1.0|.1.0",   "data": ["0", "1", "Load", "Start","WaitA"] },
  { "name": "SPI_Tx_buf",    "wave": "x.===|..==", "data": ["query_x","query_y","query_x","query_y","query_x"],},
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with the issues raised by David and add a few notes.

There are a few things that are not very good with your code, first of all, you must have a **"when  others =>"** in the list of your states. 
None of your signals seems to have a default value except the SPI_send. It also not a good idea to put the state machine inside the if statement. And if you have to do it, then you must set all the signals in both cases or else you end up with latches instead of flip-flops. One easy way to do this is to set all the signals at the begging of your code to their default value and then change them when needed.

This way the synthesis tool knows how to handle them and you get correct.

Well, this is from a VHDL-for-synthesis document from Siemence:

> **If a signal or a variable is not assigned a value in all possible**
>   **branches of an if statement, a latch is inferred**. If the intention is
>   not to infer a latch, then the signal or variable must be assigned a
>   value explicitly in **all branches of the statement**.

You can find the guide in PDF format at: http://web.ewu.edu/groups/technology/Claudio/ee360/Lectures/vhdl-for-synthesis.pdf

Comment: All of my signals have actually been set initially when they were declared, it maybe just wasn't clear since I didn't include the rest of the design. Also, what's the point in a 'when others' if there are no others? I have very clearly defined states using the a type I set up (admittedly also not shown, sorry) for SPI_action, and they're all covered in the case statement. The compiler doesn't complain at all either.

Comment: Well, that is for simulation, what I meant is that inside the process, the initial state of each signal must be known, or the signals must be set into a value under all conditions, weather there are if-else statements or case statements.